# R indexing issue

Tags: r, indexing, vectorization

Sorry for vague question title, i couldn't figure out something more specific.

I have 3x2 matrix `c`:

```
> c
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    2    3
```

It is important that `ncol(c) == 2`.

I also have matrix `ind`:

```
> ind
      [,1] [2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    2    2    1
[2,]    1    1    2    2
[3,]    2    2    2    1
```

It is important that `nrow(c) == nrow(ind)`, and that the values of matrix `ind` are 1 and 2 (like column indices for each row of c)

What i want to get is matrix `a` with same dim as `ind` such that `a[i,j] == c[i,ind[i,j]]`:

```
> a
      [,1] [2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    2    2    1
[2,]    1    1    3    3
[3,]    3    3    3    2
```

I can do something similar in less comprehensive situations, for example if `nrow(c) == 1` i'll use `apply`:

```
 > apply(c,2,function(x){return(matrix(x[ind], nrow(ind)))})
```

I know there is a way to iterate by 2 lists using mapply, but

1) i don't know what's the best way to represent matrix as list of rows
2) i fing this solution ugly

What is the best way to achieve what i descibed here?

Comment: do you want to initialize or check for boolean condition `a[i,j] == c[i,ind[i,j]]`

Comment: not sure what do you mean? WHat i meant by this is that condition is true for any i and j. But i don't know how to write it in nice vectorized form. That ideed was the issue in this thread

Comment: well, you used 2 equal to, but  now i know you want to initialize it with that equation

Comment: ah, that was'n't like a proper R statement or something. I was just saying that i'm looking to obtain `a` such that condition is true.

Comment: WARNING:  Never use "c" as an object name.  You'll run afoul of `c(stuff)`  as well as confusing this old man.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Using `c` for variables is confusing and should be avoided, but actually won't conflict with the function `c`; they're looked up in different ways.

Comment: @Aaron, that's basically true, but sooner or later "something bad" may happen.  I do agree that R is far, far better at avoiding conflicts than MatLab is.  Thank goodness for the difference between `c[` and `c(` !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matrix indexing to the rescue!

```
> c.mat <- matrix(c(1,1,2,2,3,3), ncol=2)
> ind <- matrix(c(2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,1), ncol=4)
> matrix(c.mat[cbind(as.vector(row(ind)), as.vector(ind))], ncol=ncol(ind))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    2    2    1
[2,]    1    1    3    3
[3,]    3    3    3    2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f<-function(x,row1){ 
   for(i in 1:length(x)){
     x[i]=cc[i,ind[i,row1]]
    }
   x
}
a=apply(cc,1,f,nrow(a))
```

You can use apply like this. Note: `cc` is your `c matrix`